# Classes now can't be instantiated in updated Android Studio

Tags: android

As soon as I start a new project I get this error. It asks me to build my project. I tried it several times but the problem was not solved by building the project:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/jZxXq.png]

Comment: Are you using a `Theme.AppCompat.Light` theme?

If so, you can try to extend from the base, by changing it to: `Base.Theme.AppCompat.Light`. EDIT: If you are able to build your project successfully, then just change the theme in the `Preview` and it will work fine.

Comment: Are you able to run your project even though UI wizard of studio showing you an error?

Comment: Yes the error has been corrected.It was because i was using build tools 21.1 while the compiling sdk was 23.1.